# Google Sheets. Automatically change given date plus n days

Tags: google-sheets

Good afternoon. I have 2 cells for 2 dates with date format on them and formula =DATE(2022; 1; 19). One cell is a first day of a current week period. Another cell is first day of a next week (=B17+7). I want to make both those cells to automatically change +7 days every week after i enter for example the first current date.

Comment: Difficult to understand. Please share your spreadsheet...

Comment: Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uMfJAgawFsJPG32YmdSdQ_VnmI5mGPRVU2o0JfQAc14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If, for example, I change the date in cell B13, I want both cells to work automatically in the future, adding +7 days.

Comment: There is a circular dependency error in your use case. Since you actually type a date in to cell `B13`, this cell can not hold a formula, therefore can not change automatically. You need to think of a 3 cell solution instead of 2: in the cell `A` you enter a date, only then one formula can provide the week start day in cell `B`, and yet another formula calculate the first day of next week in cell `C`. Both cell `B` and `C` can be programmed to change automatically as the days go by however cell `A` which represents the first date you entered, must remain static.

Comment: I was thinking about it. Thanks a lot. I can make a third cell to enter a date and I know by now how to add plus n days to it and post it to another cell. But what I can not do is to make all 3 of them change automatically in the future after I start the first one. Is this possible at all in google sheets?

Comment: As I said... a cell which you edit manually can not hold a formula, therefore can not change automatically. One cell (the one you entered the first date in) will always remain static.

Comment: I just not educated in this and do not know where to start looking for the answer. I think the question is obvious and I still can't do it though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241483/discussion-between-elad-ratson-and-).

Answer (score 2):

You can use for the first day (monday)

```
=today()-WEEKDAY(today(),2)+1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it is not always the monday, it is a given date plus a week (7 days).

Comment: I have added a screen shot. Indeed it is the first day of the current week!

Comment: I might not understand you, but will it work if the week period started, let say, tuesday?

Comment: change the parameter 2 of the weekday function, for instance to 3

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uMfJAgawFsJPG32YmdSdQ_VnmI5mGPRVU2o0JfQAc14/edit#gid=0 it give me an error here

Comment: change `,` to `;` , so `=today()-WEEKDAY(today();2)+1` according to your locale!

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving your need while escaping circular dependency error is to do the following:

Keep cell `B17` as is (`=B13+7`), however, instead of putting a date in cell `B13`, just put the following formula :

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1
```

The result would be that the 2 cells will always update to the correct dates every time you'd open the spreadsheet.